# UK Visa application refused under V6.2.1 (a)(c) and V6.2.1 (e)

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have been refused a UK visitor visa under Paragraph 6.2, Appendix V. This is unusual because most refusals I've seen are under [Appendix V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e'](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e?noredirect=1&lq=1)). It has been more than two years since I stopped making regular deposits in that same Ecobank account after the refusal. I have had a different account where I have been doing my regular savings for the past 18 months. Do you have any ideas on how I should go about my next application?

> **REASONS FOR REFUSAL**
>
> You have applied for a visa to visit the UK in deciding whether you
> meet the requirements of Appendix V of the Immigration Rules for
> visitors, I have considered
>
> - your application and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
>
> **The decision**
>
> I have refused your application for visit visa because I am not
> satisfied that you meet the requirement of paragraph(s) 6.2 of
> Appendix V because
>
> You plan to visit the UK for 15 days for tourism, I note that you have
> provided a bank statement in your name (account number ending 6351).
> The statement shows a regular salary Deposit which correspond with
> your stated income in support of your application.
>
> Verification checks were carried out by (DVR) Document Verification
> report held by our office. In view of this I am not satisfied that you
> have given an accurate account of your financial circumstances in your
> country of residence. Since the ECO Bank account number provided is
> inactive. On balance, I am not satisfied that your circumstances,
> coupled with your reasons for wishing to travel to the UK, are such
> that you have shown your intentions are as stated or that you intend
> to leave the UK at the end of your proposed visit.
>
> In light of all of the above, I am not satisfied that you are
> genuinely seeking entry or stay for a purpose that is permitted under
> the visitor route or that you will leave the UK at the end of your
> visit. I am not satisfied that you have sufficient funds for your
> visit. Your application is refused under V6.2.1 (a)(c) and V6.2.1 (e).
>
> **FUTURE APPLICATIONS**
>
> Any future UK visa application you make will be considered on their
> individual merits however you are likely to be refused unless the
> circumstances of your application change

Comment: Looks like it could be a ‘fat finger’ error. Not sure it really matters unless you can make a new application with documentation that refutes their conclusion about the validity of your bank statement

Comment: 'Fat finger ' error by visa officer?

Comment: It has been more than 2 years now since I stopped making a regular deposits in that same Ecobank account after the refusal...I have a different account where I do my regular savings for the past 18 months now..please do you have an idea on how I should go about my next application?

Comment: There is no paragraph V6.2 in the current immigration rules, so as @Traveller pointed up, it is likely a typing mistake (V4.2 -> V6.2.1) from the immigration officer.

Comment: Please who can perfectly help me with a better explanation for this refusal reason because my account was active and I had been receiving my salaries from that Ecobank Account..I done understand why the immigration officer would give me such reason.

Comment: Can you clarify when you received that refusal and when you stopped using that account? I’m a bit confused here…

Comment: I received the refusal letter in Jan 2020 then I went straight to the bank with my refusal letter to request a letter to prove that my account has been active since my salary has always been passing throughout. The bank refused to give me a letter so I had to change my bank to a different one because I was disappointed in their service.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake appears to have been to provide a bank statement that did not pass UKVI’s document verification check. If you reapply, that's what you need to explain and fix.

Edit: in response to your latest comment about having a different account now, see [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)